# Making a haskell program run in (roughly) a constant amount memory

Tags: haskell, csv, evaluation, strict

I'm trying to take in a CSV file, error check it and then print error messages.

mapM_ (appendFile filePath) (errorCheck function that returns a [string])

This works but when i run it but on very long CSVs it runs out of memory.
I think the problem is that it is too lazy and its loading the whole CSV into memory before it does anything. I've tried inforcing strictness using BangPatterns but i'm not sure if i'm using it correctly as it isn't helping

I can provide more information or code but I'm not sure what's relevant for my problem

Code:

```
main = do
    safeRead s = catch (readFile s) $ \_ -> return ""

    filePath <- safeRead "in.txt"
    file <- safeRead filePath

    --save the errors
    writeFile (createErrorFilePath filePath) (getFileName $ filePath ++ "\n")
    let !addToErr = do appendFile (createErrorFilePath filePath) 

    mapM_ addToErr (map ('\n':) (errorCheckFile (( \(Right x) -> x )  (parseCSV file)) (errorCheckCols (checkCols . head $ (( \(Right x) -> x )  (parseCSV file))) errorMsgs)))
    --exit with correct number
    exitWith . ExitFailure . exitCtrl $ (errorCheckFile (( \(Right x) -> x )  (parseCSV file)) (errorCheckCols (checkCols $ head $ (( \(Right x) -> x )  (parseCSV file))) errorMsgs)) 

--decides what value to exit with, depends on if errors, warnings or nothing
exitCtrl :: [String] -> Int
exitCtrl [] = 1
exitCtrl (line:rest) 
    | ("ERROR:") == take 6 line = 3
--    | elem ("WARNING:") line = 1
    | otherwise = exitCtrl rest

--gets a files name given a filepath                
getFileName :: String -> String
getFileName filePath =  reverse $ takeWhile (/= '\\') (reverse filePath)

--changes the input filepath to create a new error file at the same location
createErrorFilePath :: String -> String
createErrorFilePath pathIn = (reverse $ drop 4 (reverse pathIn)) ++ "_error_log.txt"

--check if any of the columns errored
errorCheckCols :: [Int] -> [String] -> String
errorCheckCols cols errors 
    | errorPos == Nothing = "All headings are accounted for :)"
    | otherwise = errors !! (fromJust errorPos)
        where errorPos = findIndex (== 1-2) cols

--This takes the file and if any of the columns don't exists, tells you, otherwise it error checks the database    
errorCheckFile :: [[String]] -> String -> [String]
errorCheckFile [] _ = ["ERROR: No Data"]
errorCheckFile (headings:[]) colErrorMsg = ["ERROR: No Data"]
errorCheckFile (headings:info) colErrorMsg
    | length headings > 25 = ["ERROR: Too many Columns of data"]
    | colErrorMsg == "All headings are accounted for :)" = 
            checkDB 
                info 
                (findCol "example name 1" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 2" headings 5) 
                (findCol "example name 3" headings 5) 
                (findCol "example name 4" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 5" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 6" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 7" headings 8) 
                (findCol "example name 8" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 9" headings 15) 
                (findCol "example name 10" headings 15) 
                (findCol "example name 11" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 12" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 13" headings 9) 
                (findCol "example name 14" headings 16) 
                (findCol "example name 15" headings 9) 
                (findCol "example name 16" headings 16) 
                (findCol "example name 17" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 18" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 19" headings 8) 
                (findCol "example name 20" headings 3) 
                ((findCol "example name 21" headings 20) + (findCol "example name 21 alt" headings 20) + 1) 
                (findCol "example name 22" headings 22) 
                (findCol "example name 23" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 24" headings 3) 
                (findCol "example name 25" headings 9) 
                1
    | otherwise = [colErrorMsg]



--given the inputs headings, finds the positions if each row by name 
checkCols :: [String] -> [Int]
checkCols headings = [(findCol "example name 1" headings 3),
                (findCol "example name 2" headings 5), 
                (findCol "example name 3" headings 5), 
                (findCol "example name 4" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 5" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 6" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 7" headings 8), 
                (findCol "example name 8" headings 3),
                (findCol "example name 9" headings 15), 
                (findCol "example name 10" headings 15), 
                (findCol "example name 11" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 12" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 13" headings 9), 
                (findCol "example name 14" headings 16), 
                (findCol "example name 15" headings 9), 
                (findCol "example name 16" headings 16), 
                (findCol "example name 17" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 18" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 19" headings 8), 
                (findCol "example name 20" headings 3), 
                ((findCol "example name 21" headings 20) + (findCol "example name 21 alt" headings 20) + 1), 
                (findCol "example name 22" headings 22), 
                (findCol "example name 23" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 24" headings 3), 
                (findCol "example name 25" headings 9)]


-- [[String]] Intx25 Int(count) returns a [String]
checkDB :: [[String]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String]
checkDB [] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = ["ERROR: Filename given does not exist"]
checkDB (lastRow:[]) pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 pos24 pos25 count
    | map (toUpper) (lastRow !! pos4) == "ASD" = checkASD lastRow pos1 pos2 pos3 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 count
    | map (toUpper) (lastRow !! pos4) == "QWE" || map (toUpper) (lastRow !! pos4) == "DPS" = checkQWE lastRow pos1 pos2 pos3  pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos18 pos19 pos24 pos25 pos17 count 
    | otherwise = ["ERROR: identifier not valid on line " ++ (show count)]
checkDB (firstRow:otherRows) pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 pos24 pos25 count
--    | count `mod` 50 == 0 = []
    | map (toUpper) (firstRow !! pos4) == "ASD" = checkASD firstRow pos1 pos2 pos3 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 count ++ checkDB otherRows pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 pos24 pos25 (count+1)
    | map (toUpper) (firstRow !! pos4) == "QWE" || map (toUpper) (firstRow !! pos4) == "DPS" = checkQWE firstRow pos1 pos2 pos3  pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos18 pos19 pos24 pos25 pos17 count ++ checkDB otherRows pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 pos24 pos25 (count+1)
    | otherwise = ["ERROR: identifier not valid on line " ++ (show count)] ++ checkDB otherRows pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 pos24 pos25 (count+1) 

--collection of error checking methods for ASD rows
checkASD :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String]
checkASD row pos1 pos2 pos3 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos17 pos18 pos19 pos20 pos21 pos22 pos23 count
    | sum ans == 0 = []
    | (findIndex (>=20) ans /= Nothing && findIndex (>0) ans /= Nothing) = ["WARNING: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ (show (cols!!(fromJust(findIndex (>=20) ans)) + 1))]
    | findIndex (>=20) ans /= Nothing = ["WARNING: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ (show (cols!!(fromJust(findIndex (>=20) ans)) + 1)) ++ "\nERROR: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ unwords( map show( map (+1) (map (cols!!) (findIndices (>0) (init ans)))))]
    | otherwise = ["ERROR: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ unwords( map show( map (cols!!) (findIndices (>0) ans))) ]
    where 
         ans = [errorCheck (row!!pos1) ["01","02","03","04","05"],
                errorCheck (row!!pos2) ["3","4"],
                errorCheck (row!!pos3) ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"],
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos5) isDigit 5,
                sum [ checkLength (row!!pos6) 12, errorCheckNL (row!!pos6) ],
                checkDate (row!!pos7),
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos8) checkSex 1,
                checkDate (row!!pos9),
                checkDate (row!!pos10),
                checkLength (row!!pos11) 5,
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos12) isDigit 5,
                checkMoney (row!!pos13),
                checkMoney (row!!pos14),
                checkMoney (row!!pos15),
                checkMoney (row!!pos16), 
                checkLength (row!!pos17) 10,
                checkLength (row!!pos18) 2,
                checkDate (row!!pos19), 
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos20) isDigit 5,
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos21) isDigit 5,
                checkLength (row!!pos22) 1,
                checkLength (row!!pos23) 1]
         cols = [pos1, pos2, pos3, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9, pos10, pos11, pos12, pos13, pos14, pos15, pos16, pos17, pos18, pos19, pos20, pos21, pos22, pos23]
         --cols is a quick fix for finding where errors have occured

--collection of error checking methods for QWE/DPS rows
checkQWE :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String]    
checkQWE row pos1 pos2 pos3 pos5 pos6 pos7 pos8 pos9 pos10 pos11 pos12 pos13 pos14 pos15 pos16 pos18 pos19 pos24 pos25 pos17 count
    | sum ans == 0 = []
    | (findIndex (>=20) ans /= Nothing && findIndex (>0) ans /= Nothing) = ["WARNING: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ (show (cols!!(fromJust(findIndex (>=20) ans)) + 1))]
    | findIndex (>=20) ans /= Nothing = ["WARNING: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ (show (cols!!(fromJust(findIndex (>=20) ans)) + 1)) ++ "\nERROR: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ unwords( map show( map (+1) (map (cols!!) (findIndices (>0) (init ans)))))]
    | otherwise = ["ERROR: At line " ++ (show count) ++ " at column(s) " ++ unwords( map show (map (cols!!) (findIndices (>0) ans))) ]
    where
         ans = [errorCheck (row!!pos1) ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],
                errorCheck (row!!pos2) ["1","2","3","4"],
                errorCheck (row!!pos3) ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32"],
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos5) isDigit 5,
                sum [ checkLength (row!!pos6) 12, errorCheckNL (row!!pos6) ],
                checkDate (row!!pos7),
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos8) checkSex 1,
                checkDate (row!!pos9),
                checkDate (row!!pos10),
                checkLength (row!!pos11) 5,
                checkTypeLength (row!!pos12) isDigit 5,
                checkMoney (row!!pos13),
                checkMoney (row!!pos14),
                checkMoney (row!!pos15),
                checkMoney (row!!pos16),
                checkLength (row!!pos18) 2,
                checkDate (row!!pos19),
                checkDate (row!!pos24), 
                checkMoney (row!!pos25),
                checkQWEpos17 (row!!pos17)]
         cols = [pos1, pos2, pos3, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9, pos10, pos11, pos12, pos13, pos14, pos15, pos16, pos18, pos19, pos24, pos25, pos17]
         --cols is a quick fix for finding where errors have occured


--checks that a string is 'm' or 'f'
checkSex :: Char -> Bool
checkSex input 
    | toLower input == 'm' || toLower input == 'f' = True
    | otherwise = False

--finds if a row has something other than 1 type and are of a certain length
checkTypeLength :: String -> (Char -> Bool) -> Int -> Int
checkTypeLength [] _ _ = 1
checkTypeLength el isType maxSize
    | length el > 0 && length el <= maxSize && (and $ map isType el) = 0
    | otherwise = 1

--finds elements that exceed a certain length
checkLength :: String -> Int -> Int
checkLength [] _ = 1
checkLength el maxSize
    | length el <= maxSize && length el > 0 = 0
    | otherwise = 1

--finds a columns position given its name and the list of column names, else returns -1
findCol :: String -> [String] -> Int -> Int
findCol colName header unique   --unique is the number of letters of each word that need to be compared
    | findMatch /= Nothing = fromJust findMatch
    | otherwise = -1
    where findMatch = findIndex (==(map (toLower) (take unique colName))) (map (map toLower) (map (take unique) header))

--finds if a line where the element is not a letter and number ONLY, returns col num or 0
errorCheckNL :: String -> Int
errorCheckNL [] = 1
errorCheckNL (el1:el2:el3:rest)
    | isDigit el1 && isDigit el2 && isDigit el3 && and(map isLetter rest) = 0 --return Nothing?
    | otherwise = 2
errorCheckNL others = 3

-- given a row, the column num to check, options of what the column and a counter==0, returns row num or 0
errorCheck :: String -> [String] -> Int
errorCheck [] _ = 1
errorCheck el options 
    | map toLower el `elem` options = 0
    | otherwise = 1

--finds if a date is valid given a row, the column num to check and a counter=0, returns row num or 0
checkDate :: String -> Int
checkDate [] = 1
checkDate el 
    | sepPos1 == Nothing = 1 --error: this is not formated as a date, there's no separator
    | sepPos2 == Nothing = 2 --error: this is not formated as a date, there's no separator
    | day `notElem` ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"] = 3
    | (map toLower month) `notElem` ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"] = 4   --error: month is not valid
    | length (tail year) == 4 && and (map isDigit (tail year)) = 22
    | length (tail year) == 2 && and (map isDigit (tail year)) = 0
    | otherwise = 5
    where 
        sepPos1 = findIndex (== '-') el            --maybe
        (day, rest) = splitAt (fromJust sepPos1) el
        sepPos2 = findIndex (== '-') (tail rest)   --maybe
        (month, year) = splitAt (fromJust sepPos2) (tail rest)

--checks that quantities of money are presented correctly
checkMoney :: String -> Int
checkMoney [] = 4
checkMoney cash 
    | decimalPoint == Nothing && checkTypeLength cash isDigit 9 /= 0 = 1  --error: not numbers
    | decimalPoint /= Nothing && checkTypeLength (tail cents) isDigit 2 /= 0 = 2 --error: not numbers after the decimal point
    | decimalPoint /= Nothing && checkTypeLength euros isDigit 9 /= 0 = 3 --error: not numbers after the decimal point
    | otherwise = 0
    where
        decimalPoint = findIndex (== '.') cash     --maybe
        (euros, cents) = splitAt (fromJust decimalPoint) cash
```

Comment: Yes, we'd like to see your code.

Comment: What are your imports? Which version of `readFile` are you using?

Comment: in.txt is just a filepath to the import CSV file (it's just the base ReadFile)

Comment: the second file is the error file that i've created, that works fine though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit of code

```
(( \(Right x) -> x )  (parseCSV file))
```

says that it's almost impossible that `parseCSV` can parse the file incrementally and start returning parts of the result without having consumed the entire file. And it's impossible if

- `parseCSV`'s result shall be `Left something` in case of a malformed input, and `Right result` in case of a well-formed input and
- the entire input shall be consumed if it is well-formed

Before the complete input has been consumed, one cannot know whether the parse will be successful, so it's not possible to determine whether the result is `Left errorMessage` or `Right result`.

Also, you consume the parse result twice, once for appending the messages to the log file, and once to determine the exit code. The second use holds a reference to it, so it (or, in case of multiple evaluations, the file contents) cannot be garbage collected.

On another note, you use that piece of code in four places. Depending on how the compiler does common subexpression elimination, the file is parsed up to four times. It's safer to bind the parse result to a name to avoid multiple evaluations.

If you **know** that your file is well-formed, you can reduce the space usage by parsing the file in chunks, e.g. line-wise and doing the traversal only once (logging and determining of exit code combined). A suitable pattern for that traversal is `Control.Monad.foldM`,

```
logAndUpdate file exitCode record = do
    appendFile file (message record)
    return $! update exitCode (exitInfo record)
```

In main:

```
exitCode <- foldM (logAndUpdate filename) 0 (parsedRecords)
exitWith $ ExitCode exitCode
```

A similar strategy is possible if the lines are independent, so that the presence of malformed lines doesn't affect the treatment of well-formed lines before and after, then each line would be parsed to `Either ParseError Record`. If a malformed line affects only following lines, but not previous, it's still possible by stopping the parse or switching the parser upon encountering a malformed line.

But if a malformed line invalidates the entire file, it may be impossible to do it in more-or-less constant space. It could be done in two passes, one for checking well-formedness and one for parsing, if the expected structure allows that.

Comment: Thanks this is really useful, I can follow the logic of what your doing here but I'm still a bit stuck on the implementation. 
Is 'parsedRecords' the range of records that I'm doing in a batch(lets say 30 parsed lines)?

Is there somewhere I can see the type signature for update? (where is it imported from?)

Comment: I intended `parsedRecords` to be the list of all records, produced lazily. Without knowing more about the specific situation, I can't provide any details, though.

Comment: ok, I should be able to do that.

I looked up update in hoogle but don't really see a relevent implementation, it's not seudo code is it?
Thanks for the quick responses :)

Comment: Yes, `update` is to be written by you, it would determine the exit code from the old value and any new relevant info obtained from the currently processed record. It would be closely related to your `exitCtrl`.

Comment: Thanks again, This is what I was trying to accomplish